# Cordova plugin not working in mobilefirst 8

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, command-line-interface

I have installed cordova plugin from command CLI using following cmd code snippet.
 cmd snippet: `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-progress`
After execution of above cmd, "Progress" named folder appeared in "plugins" folder of main project. I can see plugin registered in `fetch.json` as follows:

```
"cordova-plugin-progress": {
        "source": {
            "type": "registry",
            "id": "cordova-plugin-progress"
        },
        "is_top_level": true,
        "variables": {}
    }
```

I am trying to use plugin in code as progress.show("Loading...");
It doesn't work out. Please let me know where is the problem.                                         Thanks,

Comment: How is this an issue with MFP 80? Does this happen only with MFP cordova plugin added ? Or even without it?

Comment: Check same plugin in non mfp app.. if it will work then sure it will work for mfp app.

Comment: Mention what platform are you trying this on

Comment: Please provide enough facts/stacktrace/logs on the issue. Do you even use the cordova-plugin-mfp? Your question states you have installed cordova plugin from command CLI. How is this related to MFP?

Comment: I have installed cordova-plugin-mfp in Mobilefirst 8 platform. In that example, I have added cordova-plugin-progress. But, it doesn't work. Code in JS file:  progress.show("Loading...");   //display progress           
       I have tried most of plugins like progress,spinner,splash etc.       
       But none of them works. It seems that plugin not getting detected from js.             Whether I have to do anything extra other then adding plugin from CLI.

Comment: So , with or without "cordova-plugin-mfp", you see the problem, yes?

Answer (score 0):

**cordova-plugin-progress** is only supported in iOS. So check in iOS instead of android.

Also this is not related to MobileFirst.

[image]

Comment: It is not working for any of the cordova plugins such as device, cordova-plugin-spinner etc. If I am trying to display alert(device.platform); , It returns null value. It seems that cordova plugin not detected in cordova environment. Please let me know where is the problem.